# Filter by two where conditions - Firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I have lot of data in my **Firestore** collection. I have filtered data in my app but I want to cross check it from the console. In order to do that I want to apply **two where** conditions -

1. where condition for **userid**, and
2. where condition for date

But in console it seems, I can only select one field for where condition,

**How can I filter with multiple where condition in console?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible.  Feel free to file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Doug, that is currently not supported.

Is not possible (at the moment) in Firestore to perform **range filters** (example: <, <=, >, >=) on multiple fields.

An **equal/not equal** on one field with a **range filter** on another should work.

Please refer to the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries.